# ItemsPresenter crashes XAML designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have the following TreeView in my Windows XAML

```
<TreeView Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model.Files}"
      TreeViewItem.Collapsed="TreeViewItem_OnCollapsed">
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" Visibility="Hidden"
                                      ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander" />
                        <Border
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="Bd"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                ContentSource="Header" Name="PART_Header"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems">
                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                                    TargetName="Expander">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <x:Static Member="Visibility.Hidden" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Trigger.Value>
                                <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                            </Trigger.Value>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DynamicResource
                                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DynamicResource
                                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Trigger.Value>
                                <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                            </Trigger.Value>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                                    <Condition.Value>
                                        <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                                    </Condition.Value>
                                </Condition>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive">
                                    <Condition.Value>
                                        <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                                    </Condition.Value>
                                </Condition>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DynamicResource
                                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DynamicResource
                                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DynamicResource
                                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Trigger.Value>
                                <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
                            </Trigger.Value>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:FileData}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Grid.Column="0" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="3"
                       Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=Foreground}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiToVisual}">
                                <Binding Path="." />
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay"
                                         Source="{StaticResource appbar_folder}" />
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay"
                                         Source="{StaticResource appbar_folder_open}" />
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay"
                                         Source="{StaticResource appbar_page}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And the XAML designer in VS2015 is crashing width `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException`. However if I remove `ItemsPresenter` from the `ControlTemplate`, then the XAML designer starts working again.

Either way it compiles and runs, although without the `ItemsPresenter` I don't get the expected tree like result.

Am i doing something wrong? why does the XAML designer crash? Could this come back to bite me if i ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok solved this

Moving the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` from `TreeView.ItemTemplate` into `TreeView.Resources` fixes the problem.

Go figure